# C Algorithm to determine the largest polygon out of a dot matrix

Tags: c, algorithm

Here's a question which annoyed me through the night.

Given a set of points, say:

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

the largest polygon is a 4x4 square.  For this:

```
0 0 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

the largest is the trapezoid, but there will be irregular, and other variations...

How to determine the largest possible? (The largest means the one cannot be enclosed by any other polygon) What kind of algorithm should I use?

Also they need other attributes, like area, perimeter, convex(t/f), and number of invariant rotations...

---

This is provided in the instruction but I don't really understand what exactly it is about...

> Call *encoding* any 2-dimensional array of size between between 2x2 and 50x50 (both dimensions can be different),
>   all of whose elements are either 0 or 1.
>   Call *neighbour* of a member `m` of an encoding any of the at most eight members of the array whose value is 1,
>   and each of both indexes differs from `m`'s corresponding index by at most 1. Given a particular encoding, we
>   inductively determine for all natural numbers `d` the set of polygons of depth `d` (for this encoding) as follows:
>
> Let a
>   natural number `d` be given, and suppose that for all d<sub>0</sub> < d, the set of polygons of depth d<sub>0</sub> has been determined.
>   Change in the encoding all 1's that determine those polygons to 0. Then the set of polygons of depth d is determined
>   as the set of polygons which can be obtained from that encoding by connecting 1's with some of their neighbours
>   in such a way that we obtain a maximal polygon (that is, a polygon which is not included in any other polygon
>   obtained from that encoding by connecting 1's with some of their neighbours).

Comment: Interesting question. Find the "island" which contains the most ones. Sounds like a recursive search.

Comment: Will they always be filled? By "largest", do you mean the largest area or the largest perimeter? Also, have you attempted to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Is it a math puzzle or you are asking for a code? In both cases I am going to vote for close.

Comment: yup its morning in Aus, this one bothered me the whole night

Comment: @haccks Im asking for an algorithm

Comment: @Gangadhar havent come up with any algorithm yet

Comment: @Blender the definition of Max given is that it can be enclosed in any other possible polygon

Comment: So, something like a [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?

Comment: @Dukeling Didn't find a way to apply that...Since there is no fixed point to start with...

Comment: @Liduo What do you mean by fixed starting point? The convex hull gives the surrounding shape given a set of points. Convex hull algorithms are probably not appropriate for use in a matrix, but I'm just trying to make sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @DUkeling I mean the set of points is not given, I have to find them

Comment: I think I would start at the margin, "walk" inward and search (randomly or in some organized fashion, perhaps spiraling inward) to find the object, then "walk" around it's border, keeping a log of sorts.  The log should let you describe the polygon.  (Of course, if there is the possibility of more than one object then it gets messier.)

Comment: @Liduo: Just walk through the entire grid. Once you hit a `1`, start a divide-and-conquer search in all four directions and flip all of the `1`s you come across into `0`s. Walking through the entire grid like this will give you a set of points for every shape. From there, it's just a matter of finding if a set of points is included in another.

Comment: @Blender actually it have 8 neighbors... I wonder if it is too messy to brute force through this...I had look into wall follower maze solving algorithm but it looks like brute force also.

Comment: Your definition of "largest" doesn't make sense.  It's simple to construct two polygons neither of which can be enclosed by the other.  The second paragraph of the quoted instruction doesn't seem to make sense either, for the same reason.  Does "largest" mean the polygon with the greatest area?

Comment: Are you just looking for a [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare some integer B, set it to zero.

For every point p:
    If p has not been marked as "been":
        Mark p as "been"
        BFS/DFS from p and count the number of adjacent reachable points. Also mark each of these points as "been".
        If the number of reachable points + 1 is greater than B:
            B = the number of reachable points + 1
```

At the end, B = the maximum size of the polygon (in points "covered").

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm too impatient, but I found the instructions you were given about clumsy and I can see why you found them difficult to understand.

You've already designated an answer, but here are some related topics you may wish to explore.

The convex hull may be want you want. The convex hull is often described as though the points in 2D space were all pegs in a pegboard. The shape of a rubber band around the outside of the pegs is the convex hull.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms

Also, the operation to shrink (or grow) the 1s and replace them with 0s sounds like a morphological "erode" operation.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)